# PhpStorm needs to create/open project every time on startup

Tags: linux, phpstorm

I run PhpStorm from JetBrains on Linux.

I have a problem with my PhpStorm, when I close and reopen it I then need to browse and select `PhpStorm2019.3/config`. When I choose the config file then I need to open/create a project again then it needs reindexing and takes 1 hour to indexed.

Can anyone help me to avoid asking for config files and open projects again and again?

Comment: 1) I'm not a Linux user .. but it looks like some file permission issue as for me TBH. Check that -- ensure that the user you are using has needed access there. 2) Check `idea.log` file for possible hints/exceptions (`Help | Show Log in ...`)

Comment: Okay i will check

Comment: @LazyOne where can i find idea.log file?

Comment: *"where can i find idea.log file?"* -- see `Help | Show Log in ...` from inside the IDE. Otherwise -- `PhpStorm2019.3/system/log`

Comment: In Idea.log it show error below:
2020-03-27 04:48:14,437 [ 229565]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - PhpStorm 2019.3.4  Build #PS-193.6911.26 
2020-03-27 04:48:14,438 [ 229566]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-03-27 04:48:14,438 [ 229566]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
2020-03-27 04:48:14,460 [ 229588]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Already shutdown

Comment: That bit does not tell me anything. Please use `Help | Contact Support...` from inside PhpStorm (when project is loaded) or via "Submit a Request" link at the top of this page: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us -- there you can privately provide any info (e.g. your logs etc)  for JetBrains Support

Comment: sorry @lazyOne, but I submitted my request to PHPStorm team but didn't get any response from their side. anyother dev from stack can help me?